# Android Ant build on a project with two source folders

Tags: android, ant

I have a project with a linked source folder. This project depends on another (remote service) project, so the **aidl files** and the classes passed across the remote interface are in a `common_src` linked folder shared between the two projects. This work just fine with Eclipse builds, (one source file, two projects,  changes in one project are reflected in the other, just as it should be).

I'd now like to do an Ant build from the command line. I managed to get another project with a single src directory building across all targets using the example `build.xml` from the SDK tools. It imports `ant_rules_r3.xml` automatically and once the `source.dir` and `out.dir` are defined in the `build.properties` it's all fairly painless.

Turning to the project with the `src` and `common_src` folders, I can't get it to build. Firstly I cut and pasted the compile target and all those it depends upon into the `build.xml` above the setup task. I added and defined the element `common_src` to the `build.properties` and added the last line shown below to the `-compile target` (copied from `ant_rules_r3.xml`) into the `build xml`:

```
  <src path="${source.absolute.dir}" />
  <src path="${gen.absolute.dir}" />
  <src path="${common_src}" /><!--ADDED-->
```

which got it further on in the build process - it could find the .java files in common_src but not the .aidl files. No surprise I realised as the aidl is a separate target. I then added

```
<src path="${common_src}" />
```

to the -aidl target in the build xml, and it failed with:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\dev\projects\Eclipse\AndroidWorkspace\MapProject\build.xml:77: aidl doesn't
 support the nested "src" element.
```

So that's got me well and truly stuck. **Ideally I'd like to modify just the build.properties file to include the common_src and pass it to the ant_rules_r3.xml but I can't think of a way of doing it. I'd be most grateful if anyone can suggest how it can be done.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to specify multiple source directory for Android library project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605899/how-to-specify-multiple-source-directory-for-android-library-project)

Comment: @Ytai If you had bothered to look at the dates of the two questions, you would have seen that this question was posted years before the one you quoted as already having an answer. I fail to see how anyone with any brains could mark this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just in case there's any interest, I thought I'd answer my own question which is now solved.

1) I defined the common_src in the build.properties

2) Added the line

```
<src path="${common_src}"
```

in an overriden compile target in the build.xml above the setup (plus overrode all the targets it depended on  by cutting/pasting from the ant_rules_r3.xml)
3) Added a new target 'aidl2' the same as 'aidl' in build.xml but which had the line

`<source path="${common_src}"` instead of

```
<source path="${source.absolute.dir}" .
```

Made aidl depend on aidl2. Overrode all the targets aidl depended on.

I also added lines like :

```
key.store=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
key.alias=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
key.store.password=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
key.alias.password=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

to the build.xml which automated the input of passwords. I finally added an install_release target to make an automatic one command build, rease and install process.

Answer (score 16):

I had a similar issue, but it seems to have been resolved for me by the following setting in my build.properties file:

```
source.dir = src;../other_project/src
```

I used a relative path to link my src to other_project, but you should be able to use an absolute path. If you do, you should probably put it in local.properties instead.

**Note:** according to the comments in build.properties, if my SDK version < 2.0 I would use this instead:

```
source-folder = src;../other_project/src
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, only that I've used ":" instead of ";" and the file I needed to edit is ant.properties, I think Android switched to including ant.properties instead of build.properties.

Comment: @marmor which version of sdk are you using? because for me this fails (20.0.1) with both : and ; Is it still working for you?

Comment: @Nappy I longer need this feature, so I haven't tested it since updating to ADT 20, you can see which file you need to edit in your ADT version by starting a new Android project, calling "android update project --path ." on it from command line, and seeing which files it created for you, look for an ant.properties file, which should contain source-folder definition.

Answer (score 6):

I can't comment because I don't have enough reputation but it if adding a source folder works with previous answers, it fails later when building jar :

```
compile:
    [javac] Compiling 463 source files to /home/xxx/documents/eclipse/xxx/deploy/xxx/bin/classes
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] Creating empty /home/xxx/documents/eclipse/xxx/deploy/xxx/bin/classes/fr/xxx/android/socialintegration/facebook/package-info.class
     [echo] Creating library output jar file...

BUILD FAILED
/home/xxx/applis/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:570: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/xxx/applis/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:680: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/xxx/applis/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:744: /home/xxx/documents/eclipse/xxx/deploy/xxx/src;../xxxdata/src does not exist.
```

The faulty part is in the building of the jar that use source.absolute.dir as a filset which in invalid for ant.

But I don't have any workaround for now and I don't understand why others have managed to make it work ...
(I'm also using sdk r20)

Comment: the same for me. When i build library it fails with `src;other-src` does not exist either with ";" or with ":".

Answer (score 2):

Add `;` separated list of sources to your `ant.properties` (don't forget to include default `src` as well):

```
source.dir=src-other;src
```

Above works fine with Android SDK Tools Revision 20.0.3+ (Project Target: Android 2.2+, API level: 8+).

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution:

update your build.xml for more than one source.dir

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14786100/2732600

Answer (score 0):

At least on later versions of the build tools, the problem is that the value put into this property gets passed into a `<property name="source.absolute.dirs" location="source.dirs"/>`. The `location` attribute doesn't know how to deal with colon / semicolon-separated paths.

The fix is very simple, just use:

```
source.absolute.dirs=src1:src2:src3
```

etc., as opposed to:

```
source.dirs=src1:src2:src3
```